# charging 24v LiFePO4 with DC power supply intended for LED strip lights

Tags: battery-charging, lifepo4

I want to charge my 200Ah, 8 cell GBS LiFePO4 using my Honda 2000 watt generator.  (I live on a boat). I have a BMS, active monitoring and all that.  I just want to make sure the below power supply is capable of  charging my batteries.  FYI. I have 1Kw of solar that does the job most of the time, but sometimes you just need dinosaur bones to get you some amps ;-) I have a small 5 amp charger that I can use from my Honda now, but I would rather get 2 x the 24v 33a units below and get the job done fast with a minimum of generator noise in my life.  It would also serve as an emergency power for my 2000w anchor witch, IE if the battery's reach LVD I NEED to be able to get my anchor up!  Thanks for your help, I mostly ask because I am remote, and the below unit is what is available to me.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-110V-220V-TO-DC-5V-12V-24V-2A-10A-15A-20A-40A-60A-Switch-Power-Supply-Adapter/151928719853?hash=item235fa849ed:m:mGHQzsM2zsbvEUasc4rRv6Q:rk:7:pf:0

Comment: It would be highly useful if you can provide exact specifications for your "200Ah, 8 cell GBS LiFePO4", whether it has any built-in charger abilities in addition to BMS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a standard power supply as charger is the lack of (CC) Constant Current charging mode. Instead, these power supplies have hiccup type overcurrent protection, which is unsuitable for battery charging.

Yes, you could charge a battery with it, if you adjust the voltage low enough that is will never overload the supply and battery. But you will be unable to charge to 100%. Unless you manually trim the voltage keeping an eye on the charge current.

---

If you have to ask if a power supply is suitable to charge a battery, it is unsuitable.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I got a power supply with CC.  However by controlling voltage on it I can also control current, so the above supply would have worked, but with no CC it could also burn out if the voltage was too high